# Passing UIButton by reference

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

Hi I am new to iOS programming. I am writing a iOS application and implemented few UIButtons. I have to set the properties for these buttons. So instead of writing repetitive code for each button, I implemented separate method to basically set the properties.
Code is given below

```
-(void)abc{

_xCord = self.view.bounds.size.width/2.0f;
_yCord = self.view.bounds.size.height/2.0f;

[self setButtonProperties:_def]; // def is ivar UIButton 

_xCord+=50;
_yCord+=50;

[self setButtonProperties:_ghi]; // ghi is ivar UIButton}
```

Set button properties is given below

```
- (void)setButtonProperties:(UIButton *)button{


button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(_xCord, _yCord, 50, 50);

button.clipsToBounds = YES;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 50/2.0f;
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
[self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Here the button is added to view but it is not reflected with iVar UIButton.When I implement the target methods for button actions the respective methods of buttons are not called. Is there a way to send UIButton as reference or any other way I can achieve the same so that setButtonProperties method actually set ivar UIButton properties.

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are always by reference, it seems you have a problem using the wrong references, or you don't have a reference at all

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the ivar by reference like this (adding & to the ivars and adjusting the setButtonProperties method). But since your code really don't need this I suggest your code returns the button like Pravin Tate suggests.

```
-(void)abc{

    _xCord = self.view.bounds.size.width/2.0f;
    _yCord = self.view.bounds.size.height/2.0f;

    [self setButtonProperties:&_def]; // def is ivar UIButton

    _xCord+=50;
    _yCord+=50;

    [self setButtonProperties:&_ghi]; // ghi is ivar UIButton}

    NSLog(@"foo");
}

- (void)setButtonProperties:(UIButton * __strong *)button{


    *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    (*button).frame = CGRectMake(_xCord, _yCord, 50, 50);

    (*button).clipsToBounds = YES;
    (*button).layer.cornerRadius = 50/2.0f;
    (*button).layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    (*button).layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:*button];
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know how to dereference the pointer using (UIButton * __strong *). It Worked. However Pravin Tate approach did not work.

Comment: No, his example is only half baked. It should be something like  _def=[self setButtonProperties]; [self.view addSuvView:_def]; and remove the unnecessary argument to setButtonProperties.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same reference of the new button object which you create on this method, you need to have your method like this:

```
- (void)setButtonProperties:(UIButton **)button{


    UIButton *tempBbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    tempBbutton.frame = CGRectMake(_xCord, _yCord, 50, 50);

    tempBbutton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    tempBbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 50/2.0f;
    tempBbutton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    tempBbutton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:tempBbutton];
    *button = tempButton;
}
```

This is how the error object is created and saves on the same memory of the error object (&error) which we pass on method.